# how to detect power cycle on philips hue bridge?

Tags: philips-hue

How can I detect power outage on bridge? I tried using CLIP sensor daylight's lastupdated object and checked it against none but it does not help. As per meet hue description of 'lastupdated' object, it should none.

"Last time (based on /config/utc) the sensor send state data reflected in the state field. No value change is required to update the field. “none” (asof 1.x.0 null) when not initialized/no recent update has been received since the last bridge power cycle
"
But it always returns as timestamp. Can somebody suggest a way out please?

regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a CLIPGenericStatus sensor and set it to a value that is not 0.
When the bridge restarts it will be 0 again.

You don't describe how you want to use this value (read it with by external process or trigger a rule on the bridge), but this is an indicator that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

A Philips support developer recently came up with a solution on the meethue forums.

> The idea here is that schedules start running when the bridge boots
>   and the state of a ClipGenericStatus sensor initiates its status to 0
>   after a reboot. This might be subject to change.
>
> 1. Create a ClipGenericStatus sensor.
> 2. Create a schedule that will change the status of the above ClipGenericStatus sensor to 1 every 10 to 15 seconds.
> 3. Create a rule that will do something with the lights when the above ClipGenericStatus sensor is equal to 1.   The rule can for example
>      turn off all lights if the time is between 23.00 and 07.00.   Some
>      downsides are:
>
>    - It will also trigger when there is a reboot after disconnecting and connecting the powercord manually.
>    - It will also trigger when there is a reboot after bridge firmware update or internal crash.
>    - This isn't a solution for configurable startup behaviour.
>    - Going back to last state, with saving all lightstates to a scene at a specific interval, is not recommended as it will degrade the life
>        expectancy of the lamps involved.

Link to original post: https://developers.meethue.com/comment/2918#comment-2918